# How can i send hyperlink to email on Grafana alert?

Tags: outlook, gmail, grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

I’m setting up the alerting template and i want to send a hyperlink to user email.
But when user receive the email the link doesn’t convert to hyperlink and it showed as plain text instead.

If i send the email to Outlook, the link doesn’t showed as hyperlink. But if I send to Gmail, the link will auto generate to hyperlink.

Does anyone know how can i solve this issue? Thanks.

My settings:

[image]

Result in Outlook:

[image]

If i forward the message from gmail to outlook, then its working lol:

[image]